# How to write a simple interpreter in C++?

Tags: c++, interpreter

How to write a simple interpreter for a simple language in C++ that gets a .txt file as input and runs that.

** Just for `+` `-` `/` `*` `out` functions **

Input (Source code) :

```
int a,b,c;
a=2;
b=4;
c=a+b;
out c;
```

Interpreter output :

```
6
```

How i can do this ? Any help or source code appreciated.

Sorry if u didn't get my question, My English is so bad. Just ignore the " Interpreter " for a sec . I want to write an console program in C++ that gets a txt file as source code and recognize the basic math and "out" command . is it possible in C++ or not ?

Comment: Are you allowed to use yacc and lex for this ?

Comment: @Paul R  I don't think so.

Comment: There is not too many possible answers: there are specific math to solve this questions and the way to implement that is not wider than for any other question. How to remove this "Hold"?

Comment: If you don't want to reinvent the wheel: http://boost-spirit.com/

Comment: Look into embeddable interpreters like [Lua](http://lua.org/) or [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/). See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27554300/841108) & [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25317439/841108) & [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29816531/841108) and the references I'm giving there.

Comment: @AdrianMaire The question is basically "how do I create interpreter in C++ for a language like this?", and I'd say that is definitely in the "too broad" category. There are just too many valid ways to do it, especially with language like C++.

Comment: @Emperor280 your question is off-topic here because it is not related to source code. And it would be off-topic on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) because it is too broad and does not show any prior research

Comment: @hyde: No, look my answer, the path is quite defined. You could also define which of the syntax to use, but I did not get so far. Supposing for example a LALR(1) you could even set a pseudo-algorithm.

Comment: @AdrianMaire: the bulk of any interpreter is not [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing), but interpreting, I.e. defining the [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_%28computer_science%29) of the scripting language, then coding the interpreter.

Comment: @AdrianMaire The question asks about C++, you answer doesn't really cover that. But perhaps it's the question, which should be edited to use [tag:pseudocode], or just not have "language" tag in it.

Comment: @hyde: probably you are right and the C++ tag should be removed or switched to pseudo-code. I think we should be more careful in tagging new users, that is very de-motivating. Usually an explanation/correction is more constructive.

Comment: *"is it possible in C++ or not ?"*, obviously it is possible... In about 100 different ways. If you want to do it yourself from scratch, work in small steps (as always in programming). You *could* start by writing a tokenizer, which recognizes your two keywords (`int` and `out`), numbers and operators (`=+-*/`). You could create a token class, and then have `std::vector<token>`, where you put the tokens. Once you have code which can create such a vector (and give syntax/parse error message when parsing fails), you can start looking into what to do with the tokens...

Answer (score 4):

An interpreter is usually made in 3 steps:

**Lexical**
Recognize specific simple shemes, like keyword, numbers, symbols, etc. The standard way is to define a regular expression for each lexer. There are well defined algorithm there outside to transform a reg-exp in a state machine so you may recognize any work in your input.

This is made by:

- Create a state machine from each regexp
- Join all state machines
- Make the state machine deterministic
- Make the state machine minimal.

**Syntax**
In this part, you get the sequence of lexer as input and create a tree with them. Depending on the complexity of your language, there are different types: top->down or down->top. (speaking about LR, LL, LALR, etc.)

```
file
|...
|- c=a+b
|  |- a+b
      |- a
      |- +
      |- b
   |- =
   |-c
```

**Semantic**
Go trough your tree and make the operations, so for example in the a+b, you get the a, the b and you sum them, then you return to the above node, and set the value to c.

Final note:
Be careful to design a powerful error/warning mechanism from the starting: type of error, full description, line and char where the mistake is detected, level of the error/warning, etc.

Also, could be interesting to provide for each node the parsed input (string), the interpreted content (LEX_NUMBER) and the interpreted value (4).

Comment: That was helpful , Thanks.